# Neo4j on the fly type conversion

Tags: neo4j

I'm just starting to learn Neo4j and I've just stumbled across some issue.

It looks like Neo4j is using strong typing without on the fly type conversion, i.e. `RETURN '17' = 17` results in `false` and `RETURN '10' > 5` results in syntax error.

It looks very strange to me for NoSQL and schema-less database to implement such a strict behavior. Even strong typed schema-based databases such as MySQL and Postgresql allows type conversions in statements. Is this an ideology behind Neo4j? If so why?

[Github issue.](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2151)

Answer (score 1):

In Neo4j 2.1 there were type conversion functions added, like `toInt` and `toFloat` that take care of the conversion.

In 2.0.x you can use `str(17) = str('17')` in the other direction.

Neo4j itself is less strict on structural information. But more strict on values. I.e. the value you put into a property is returned exactly like that and you have to convert it to a different type yourself. Some of that stems from its Java history and was already loosened for cypher.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Michael! So, if can't control that information added to shared database will be in proper strict data types I will have to add lot's of `toInt`, `toFloat`, `str` functions to all the queries? What are the best practices around this issue? Thank you )